# Replace multiple strings in file using a mapping file

Tags: string, dictionary, replace, awk

How can I replace multiple strings in one big file ( + 500K lines ) using a mapping file (+ 50K lines) ? The mapping file is structured like this :

```
A1  B1
A2  B2
A3  B3
..  ..
```

and the big file is structured like this :

```
A1  A2
A1  A3
A1  A8
A2  A1
A2  A3
A3  A10
A3  A13
```

and every string in the big file has to be replace using the mapping file.

Result wanted :

```
B1  B2
B1  B3
B1  B8
B2  B1
B2  B3
B3  B10
B3  B13
```

I tried using awk on every line of the mapping file but it takes a very very long time ... Here is the awk command. So I wrote a loop launching for each line of the mapping file an awk command, I save the results in a temporary file and use this result in a new awk with the next line of the mapping file ( not very efficient I know .. )

```
cat inputBigFile.txt | awk '{ gsub( "A1","B1" );}1' > out.txt
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Precisely what `awk` command did you try that was too slow?

Comment: Search for one of the many near-duplicates where the answer explains how to use `NR==FNR`.

Comment: Anyway, you should not `cat` data to programs that can read it itself, like `awk`. `awk '{ gsub( "A1","B1" );}1' inputBigFile.txt > out.txt`.  To see how long time program uses, start it with `time` eks: `time awk 'code` file > out`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{map[$1]=$2;next} {if($1 in map)$1=map[$1]; if($2 in map)$2=map[$2]}1' mappings file
B1
B1
B1 A8
B2
B2
B3 A10
B3 A13
```

I assume specifically checking and replacing the two columns to be faster than a loop over `NF` and/or using `gsub`.

EDIT: It significantly is:

```
$ wc -l file
8388608 file
```

.

```
$ time awk 'NR==FNR{map[$1]=$2;next} {if($1 in map)$1=map[$1]; if ($2 in map)$2=map[$2]}1' mappings file >/dev/null
real    0m6.941s
user    0m6.904s
sys     0m0.016s
```

.

```
$ time awk 'NR==FNR{map[$1]=$2;next} {for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)$i=($i in map)?map[$i]:$i}1' mappings file >/dev/null
real    0m10.311s
user    0m10.249s
sys     0m0.036s
```

.

```
$ awk --version | head -n 1
GNU Awk 3.1.8
```

Comment: Thanks that's perfect. But you forgot an $ in your awk command (in $2=map[2]) : awk 'NR==FNR{map[$1]=$2;next} {if($1 in map)$1=map[$1]; if($2 in map)$2=map[$2]}1' mappings file

Comment: One thing : how can I force to output in tab delimited ?

Comment: @NicoBxl Use `awk -v OFS='\t' [...]` to set the output delimiter. However, this will only affect lines where at least one of the columns have been changed. To force, you can add an explicit `print $1, $2` after the `if` (and drop the trailing `1`), e.g. `[...]; if($2 in map)$2=map[$2]; print $1, $2}`.